# Confused by malloc and free behaviour

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am confused with the usage of `free()` in regard to data structures in C.

If I have the following data structure:

```
struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    float weight;
    float height;
};
```

I am allocating memory for the structure via `malloc()`, likewise: `struct Person *me = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));`

After I am done with using my structure (right before ending the program), I proceed to freeing the memory allocated, like this:

```
free(person_pointer->name);
free(person_pointer);
```

Freeing the memory that the `name` pointer points to is necessary to my knowledge, because if I only free `person_pointer` *I only free the memory that was allocated to store the data structure and its members* **but not the memory that is pointed to by pointers-members of the structure.**

However with my implementation [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) seems to suggest that the first `free()` is invalid.

So my question boils down to: **When I free the memory that a struct occupies via a pointer, should I preemptively free the memory that member pointers point to or not?**

EDIT: This is my whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    float weight;
    float height;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct Person *me = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    me->name = "Fotis";
    me->age = 20;
    me->height = 1.75;
    me->weight = 75;

    printf("My name is %s and I am %d years old.\n", me->name, me->age);
    printf("I am %f meters tall and I weight %f kgs\n", me->height, me->weight);

    free(me->name);
    free(me);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mat I do malloc(). I will edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: @Mat Just updated the question with my allocating method. If you need more information, I could post my whole code, it's a rather small program, however from now I shall refrain from doing so for clarity's sake.

Comment: +1 for complete test-case, using Valgrind, etc.

Comment: @MM.: It is right. `me->name` points on an anonymous string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
me->name = "Fotis";

/* ... */

free(me->name);
```

The rule is:

```
1 malloc = 1 free
```

You didn't use `malloc` on `me->name`, so you don't have to `free` it.

BTW, `me->name` should be of `const char *` type.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
    me->name = "Fotis";
```

The `name` pointer is not alloced by malloc, it points to a stack variable which is stored in the strings table of your binary file at compile time, hence you can't free it.

The rule of thumb is : Only free what you have malloced.

You can't update this read-only string though.

If you did something like :

```
me->name = strdup("Fotis");
```

Since strdup does a malloc (see the manual), you have to free it, and you can update the string after its creation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to free all the memory of pointers inside the structure if you allocated them.

Also make sure you free the members before you free the structure.

A simple way to remember is free them  in the reverse order in which you have allocated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you didn't actually malloc'ed the char * name inside your structure.

```
struct Person *me = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
me->name = strdup("Fotis");
...
free(me->name);
free(me);
return (0);
```

When you write this

```
me->name = "Fotis";
```

You don't actually malloc, the pointer name points to a stack variable of type `const char *`, wich is not malloc'ed.

Comment: `strdup` is not a standard-library function.  Probably best not to recommend it...

Comment: The string literal is stored statically, not on the stack. A pointer to it would be valid in any function anywhere in the program.